# iOS: Socket Connection Error in sending buffer

Tags: ios, sockets, network-programming, inputstream, outputstream

We have tried too many diffrent approaches to solve our issue and also searched over net but we only found example of sending string and not the byte array. We require to send byte array through socket connection. Please read issue explanation below.

We require to connect wi-fi device with iOS app. We have successfully connected the device but when we send the command in byte array format, It is returning NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable in response. Which is wrong, We require NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable event.

Below is the code for connection:

```
-(void) initNetworkCommunication:(NSString*)strHostName {

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)strHostName, 2000, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;



[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

}
```

When connection is open, we are calling below method to send the command:

```
 - (IBAction) sendCommand {
 unsigned char *buffer[5] = {0x3a,0x04,0x01,0x07,0x0c};

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:5];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:5];

}
```

So there is some issue in sendCommand method because we are receiving NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable and that is wrong. Because it should be returned NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable in the response.  Can any one please help us how to send byte array {0x3a,0x04,0x01,0x07,0x0c} in iOS so we can receive NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable event.

According to command manual, When device receives command in correct format then it will return acknowledgement. Below is the manual description.

> All commands are 16 bits and are placed in the Data byte 1(MSB) and
>   Data byte 2(LSB).
>   The response to a command can either be a specific response relating
>   to the command or a simple response. The three simple responses are
>   ACK, NAK and UNK. An ACK signifies that the command was received
>   successfully. A NAK indicates that there was an error with either the
>   length byte or an incorrect checksum was calculated. An UNK response
>   indicates that the recipient does not recognize the command that was
>   sent.

- Value  Answer Status

  - 0x06 = ACK (OK)
  - 0x15 = NAK (NOT OK)
  - 0x09 = UNK    (Unknown command)

So we should receive any of the above flag(ACK OR NAK OR UNK) but we are receiving NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable and this is wrong. Any one please help me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` is the correct event to receive after sending data on an output stream - it indicates that you can write at least one byte without blocking (ie. There is space to write data available). `NSstreamEventHasBytesAvailable` will be signalled against an input stream when data is received on the socket associated with that input stream to indicate that you can issue a read without blocking.

If the device you are sending the data to responds to that data then I would expect you to receive `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` on `inputStream`

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. I have edited my question. Acording to command manual when we send this command, We should receive some bytes like 0x06 for ACK or any from another two. But we are receiving NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable. Please review my question again.

Comment: If you examine the stream that is passed to your delegate for the `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event you will see that it is your output stream.  You should also receive a `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` event on your input stream if the remote device is sending a response. You can also try issuing a read on the input stream

Comment: It turns out I was using some protocol that wasn't sending ACKs instead of one that was. When I figured this out and switched protocols the ACKs were coming in as described above